# OpenGraph Actions in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Here there are two tutorials how to share Open Graph Actions:

1. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/open-graph#sharedialog
2. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/publish-open-graph-story

First one does not require back-end server setup. While, the second one requires. I want to understand what is the difference of these two methods. And why I need to have a back-end server?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a server-side for your OG objects if you use the object API. In fact, if you look in the code for the Scrumptious app (shipped with the SDK), there's an example there of how to use the object API to create new user-owned OG objects (user owned objects are scoped to the user, and subject to privacy restrictions - like a Run in a fitness app).

You can also create app-owned objects using the object API. These are global objects, and may be more useful depending on your use case (like Restaurants in a rating app). For more info, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects#objectapi

Comment: Thanks for your response. Where can I find a doc that describes how to send `Ont to Two`, `One to Many` actions. I don't know how to do that. Once I send it is being published as `One to One Without Title` (I follow to first tutorial in my question.). Also cannot add custom fields to an OG object. It simply does not work and cannot find any doc related to this issue too. I will highly appreciate your help.

Comment: BTW here https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/Scrumptious/src/com/facebook/scrumptious I cannot find an example of how to use the object API to create new user-owned OG objects. Is this a wrong place to look at?

Comment: See the handleGraphApiAnnounce method in SelectionFragment.java. It does everything in a batch request, but around lines 338-344 it creates a request for a new user owned object.